# UIStackView distribution with intrinsic content size of one subview prioritised

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistackview, intrinsic-content-size

```
  stackView
+------------+                +
|  topView   | height: 50     |
+------------+                |
|            |                |
|            |                | total height: 300
| bottomView | height: 250    |
|            |                |
|            |                |
+------------+                +
```

I would like to layout two views (`topView` and `bottomView`) in a `UIStackView` (`stackView`) with these conditions:

- `stackView` has a height (let’s say 300)
- `topView`’s and `bottomView`’s intrinsic content height is the same (let’s say 50)
- `topView`’s should be rendered with its intrinsic content height (up to `stackView`’s height) (so 50)
- `bottomView` should take the remaining space (so 250)
- if `topView`’s intrinsic content height changes (let’s say to 100) the distribution should be 100/200

None of the distribution modes of UIStackView can cover this.

Setting a constraint with a constant wouldn’t help here, as the intrinsic content height of `topView` might change.

So I need some Auto Layout features here. I tried setting different content compression resistance priorities and content hugging priorities. Without success, I still feel like they could be a solution (if I knew how to use them correctly).

It doesn’t seem like a complex problem, I can’t find the right Auto Layout API for this. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set:

- **vertical content hugging priority of top view to be more than bottom view**
- alignment of stack view to fill
- distribution of stack view to fill

You should add a width constraint as well, if the top and bottom views do not have intrinsic width.

Demo:

[image] [image]

Comment: Thx! My `stackView` has a variable height though. No way to do it with a variable stack view height?

Comment: It itself is contained in a variable height container (which can be resized by the user).

Comment: @MichaelGillen Well, whether the height is dynamic or constant doesn't really matter in the context of this question, as long as it is not ambiguous. The bolded part is the key.

Comment: If the container can be resized arbitrarily, you probably want to decide what happens when the stack view's width/height is not enough to contain its contents. Then set content compression resistance priority of the two views correspondingly, but that's another question.

Comment: @MichaelGillen So did setting the content hugging priority work?

Comment: The content hugging priority did not work. I guess then there is something in my layout that prevents this from working. Will have to investigate later.

Comment: @MichaelGillen I see. Try making a [mcve].

Comment: Thx. I’ll accept your anwer as I assume the problem lies somewhere on my side ;)

Comment: @MichaelGillen - this answer is what you need. If you're not getting the same result, you may find it helpful to use 2 custom labels that allow you to specify the intrinsic height. Try it with this class: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/b0d839f5a4cffe4909a57541c9ee39d4 ... you will be able to set the `h` property for a specific intrinsic height, and the label will set its text to `IH: nnn` - the Intrinsic Height - and `AH: nnn` - the Actual Height.